# Salesforce Lookup Search - Lightning

Tags: case, lookup, search

I am at case record and want to perform a lookup search without any inputs. I have used lookup criterio in my field so that the subscriptions shown should be the ones that have as an account the one who is on the Case. But how can i show all the Subscriptions when clicking and without the need to type 3 characters?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is the standard lookup, then you won't be able to change the behavior. You will need to create a custom implementation for this.

Also from UX standpoint showing all subscriptions at one go is won't be a good idea if there are more than 10 subscriptions.

Comment: Yes, but lets say i have an Account that has 4 subscriptions (Electricity, EV Charger, Gas, PV), isn't it logical to want to see all 4 subscriptions the customer has? Ok, even by pressing the enter button, shouldn't all the subscriptions under this Account be available? So, there is not a way to overcome this? I need to create a custom implementation? (Custom Lightning Component) ?